# Ruby Web Services

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap

I'm contemplating creating a web application using a Ruby on Rails/MySQL stack and I am wondering what capabilities are available around web services and SOAP. Is there a capability within the framework or does it require an extension and if so what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails has opted for REST over SOAP in the default framework. It's not hard to go the SOAP route if you want to, though.

I don't recommend soap4r - as of a few months ago, anyway, it wasn't production quality. The updated version of [ActionWebService](http://www.datanoise.com/articles/2008/7/2/actionwebservice-is-back) has worked much better for me.

Answer (score 3):

Rails opted for [REST over SOAP](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2007/12/7/rails-2-0-it-s-done):

> It’ll probably come as no surprise
>   that Rails has picked a side in the
>   SOAP vs REST debate. Unless you
>   absolutely have to use SOAP for
>   integration purposes, we strongly
>   discourage you from doing so. As a
>   naturally extension of that, we’ve
>   pulled ActionWebService from the
>   default bundle. It’s only a gem
>   install actionwebservice away, but it
>   sends an important message none the
>   less.

Still, if you must use SOAP, there's always [soap4r](http://dev.ctor.org/soap4r), but it only supports SOAP 1.1.  A better option might be [WSF/Ruby](https://wso2.org/project/wsf/ruby/1.0.0/docs/index.html).  Mark Thomas has an [example controller](http://markthomas.org/2008/01/14/industrial-strength-web-services-for-ruby/) to help you get up and running.

Answer (score 2):

The old way in Rails was to use the [Action Web Service](http://aws.rubyonrails.org/) framework. The preferred way now is to use the [ActiveResource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics) framework for RESTful web services.

Comment: FYI, that ActionWebService link (to the APIs at rubyonrails.org) is for an old version that won't work with Rails 2. Check out the datanoise-actionwebservice on github for an updated version.